# Post request is made but only object _id is shown in MongoDB

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

please I have a contact form in my html file as below;

```
<form action="/contact" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="" placeholder="Name">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="" placeholder="Your Email">
                    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message</textarea>
                    <button type="submit" id="form_btn">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

I have a contact expressjs API which I have tested with Postman and working properly when I send a post request below;

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Contact = require('../models/Contact');

//GET BACK ALL THE POSTS
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const contacts = await Contact.find();
            res.json(contacts);
    }   catch(err){
            res.json({message: err});
    }
});

//SUBMITS A CONTACT INFORMATION
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const contact = new Contact({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        message: req.body.message,
    });
    try{
    const savedContact = await contact.save()
    res.json(savedContact);
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I also have this code in my server;

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

// Middlewares
require('dotenv/config');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// Import routes
const contactRoute = require('./contact');
app.use('/contact', contactRoute);

// Serving static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public'))); 

// Connect to DB
mongoose.connect( 
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION, 
    {  useNewUrlParser: true ,
       useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    },
    () => console.log('Connected to DB')
);

const port = process.env.PORT || 9900;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server started on port ${port}`));
```

The problem is, if I click the bottom to make a post request, the post request is made but only the object _id is shown in my MongoDB data base as;

---

{
"_id": "5e19d5e39134760ad4b2e9e1",
"__v": 0
}

---

Its so weird that the name, email, and message is not included, mean while when I make the post request from Postman, all the fields are shown as ;

---

{
        "_id": "5e16f824b1074516901951d7",
        "name": "Kwame Asare Boahen",
        "email": "Kwame@gamil.com",
        "message": "Hello, its been quite along time",
        "__v": 0
  }

---

Please Seniors, what is causing this? I have trying other means of fixing this but is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with postman because you are sending json but with the form you are sending
encoded data so you just need one more middleware

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```